# trying to use two column as key to get value from a dict: TypeError: unhashable type: 'Series'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

This is my dictionary format:

```
dictionary = {tuple:list}
```

with these keys

```
dict_keys([('102304', '15311'), ('102304', '919967')])
```

I'm trying to populate a column in a DataFrame with this row

```
df['newcol']=dictionary.get( ( [ df['x'],df['y'] ] ) )
```

but

```
 TypeError: unhashable type: 'Series'
```

I have tried to cast other type on the series, but does not work.

My final goal is to populate the new column with the "sequence" of the list in the dictionary:

```
dic = {('111','112'):[2,3,4,5,6,7,8], ('1','2'):[2,33,4,5]}
```

| x | y | newcol |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | 112 | 2 |
| 111 | 112 | 3 |
| 111 | 112 | 4 |
| 111 | 112 | 5 |
| 1 | 2 | 2 |
| 1 | 2 | 33 |

Comment: Use `map`or `merge`

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible input for `df`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) after converting the dictionary to Series, then [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) the resulting column:

```
dic = {('111','112'):[2,3,4,5,6,7,8], ('1','2'):[2,33,4,5]}
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': ['111', '1'],
                   'y': ['112', '2']
                  })

out = (df.merge(pd.Series(dic, name='newcol'),
                left_on=['x', 'y'], right_index=True, how='left')
         .explode('newcol')
      )
```

Output:

```
     x    y newcol
0  111  112      2
0  111  112      3
0  111  112      4
0  111  112      5
0  111  112      6
0  111  112      7
0  111  112      8
1    1    2      2
1    1    2     33
1    1    2      4
1    1    2      5
```

If the input DataFrame already has several duplicated rows and you want to merge in order, first `explode` the Series, then `merge` after de-duplicating with [`groupby.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumcount.html):

```
dic = {('111','112'):[2,3,4,5,6,7,8], ('1','2'):[2,33,4,5]}
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': ['111', '111', '111', '111', '1', '1'],
                   'y': ['112', '112', '112', '112', '2', '2']
                  })

out = (df
   .assign(n=lambda d: d.groupby(['x', 'y']).cumcount())
   .merge(pd.Series(dic, name='newcol').rename_axis(['x', 'y'])
            .explode().to_frame()
            .assign(n=lambda d: d.groupby(['x', 'y']).cumcount()),
          on=['x', 'y', 'n'], how='left')
  .drop(columns='n')
 )
```

Output:

```
     x    y newcol
0  111  112      2
1  111  112      3
2  111  112      4
3  111  112      5
4    1    2      2
5    1    2     33
```

Comment: I resolved it by using an iterator list in the values of the dictionary and df['newcol'] = df.apply(lambda row: next(dict.get((row['x'], row['y']))), axis=1), but your solution is much more brilliant than mine. Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: @FRE You're welcome. So which case did you have? The second one I guess? Can you please update the question with a reproducible code for `df`? This will be helpful to future readers.